# Could not open local file, but the file is there

Tags: php, linux, laravel, ubuntu

I have a php artisan command that I created, and executed as `bheng` user

```
php /home/forge/site.com/artisan products:exportdiff --env=production
```

that export the file into my `/files/product-exports/` directory

Also, I've already did

```
chmod -R 777 files/product-exports/
```

---

## Result

The export part is working fine, I got the file exported as you can see in the image below

[image]

But I kept getting this

[image]

What is the different between `white` and `green` color code ?

Why does it place under the dot `.` ? Does it mean anything at all ?

Is this something that have to do with the permission ?

---

## Update

As requested from **@Tensibai**

**cd /home/forge/site.com/ && pwd && php /home/forge/site.com/artisan products:exportdiff --env=production**

```
/home/forge/site.com

.
Export created successfully. Export ID is 1085
Source: /home/forge/site/files/product-exports/export1085_2016-11-23.csv
Destination: /Site/inbound/products/productexport1085_2016-11-23.csv
$source NOT exist !


                                                                                                           
  [Exception]                                                                                              
  Could not open local file: /home/forge/site/files/product-exports/export1085_2016-11-23.csv.  
                                                                                                           


products:exportdiff
```

---

## Update2

`$source = /home/forge/site/files/product-exports/export1088_2016-11-23.csv`

I've tried `dd(file_exists($source));`

It kept return `bool(false)`

**Is it because of the way I check for file_exists ?**

---

## Update3

Here is my whole PHP code for `ExportProductsDiff.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;

class ExportProductsDiff extends Command {

    /**
     * The console command name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name = 'products:exportdiff';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Export all products to Diff.';

    /**
     * The system export message.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $system_message = '[System Diff Export]';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function fire()
    {
        // Export the products by calling the ExportProducts Command
        $options = [
            '--format'          => "distributor",
            '--encoding'        => "standard csv",
            '--categories'      => "all categories",
            '--conjugate'       => 1,
            '--include_disabled'=> 1,
            '--export_notes'    => $this->system_message
        ];

        // Run the export
        $this->call('products:export', $options);

        $last_run_export = ProductExport::where('notes', '=', $this->system_message)
            ->where('status', '=', 'finished')
            ->where('format', '=', 'distributor')
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->firstOrFail();
        $this->info('Export created successfully. Export ID is ' . $last_run_export->id);

        $env = $this->option('env');
        if ($env == 'production'){
            $localdomain = '*******';
        }else{
            $env = 'development';
            $localdomain = '*******';
        }

        $sftp_server = '*******';
        $sftp_user_name = '*******';
        $sftp_user_pass = '*******';

        // Open the SFTP connection
        $connection = @ssh2_connect($sftp_server);
        if (!$connection)
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not connect to $sftp_server.");
        }

        // Login to the SFTP server
        if (! @ssh2_auth_password($connection, $sftp_user_name, $sftp_user_pass))
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not authenticate with username $sftp_user_name " .
                "and password $sftp_user_pass.");
        }
        $sftp = @ssh2_sftp($connection);
        if (!$sftp)
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not initialize SFTP subsystem.");
        }

        // Prepare the files
        $source = '/home/forge/site/files/product-exports/' . $last_run_export->file_name;



        /////////////////////////////////////
        //The bug is here 
        // update site to site.com 
        /////////////////////////////////////




        $destination = '/Site/inbound/products/product' . $last_run_export->file_name;

        $this->info('Source: ' . $source);
        $this->info('Destination: ' . $destination);

        if (!file_exists('/Site/inbound/products/')) {
            ssh2_sftp_mkdir($sftp, '/Site/inbound/products/', 0775, true);
        }

        dd(file_exists($source));

        if (file_exists($source)) {
            chmod($source, 0775);
        }else{
            $this->info('$source NOT exist !');
        }

        // Upload the file
        $stream = @fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp$destination", 'w');

        if (!$stream)
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not open file: $destination");
        }

        $data_to_send = @file_get_contents($source);
        if ($data_to_send === false)
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not open local file: $source.");
        }

        if (@fwrite($stream, $data_to_send) === false)
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not send data from file: $source.");
        }

        @fclose($stream);

        // Delete the export when finished
        if (file_exists(base_path() . ProductExport::path . $last_run_export->file_name))
        {
            unlink(base_path() . ProductExport::path . $last_run_export->file_name);
        }
        $last_run_export->delete();
    }

    /**
     * Get the console command arguments.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getArguments()
    {
        return array();
    }

    /**
     * Get the console command options.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getOptions()
    {
        return array();
    }

}
```

Comment: your file name ends with a dot

Comment: as you can see, it is `not` according the screenshot with a list of files.  I was thinking the same thing like you.

Comment: O_o .... what system are you running ? `pwd` should not return `.` ...

Comment: Sorry, your pwd is printing. I was just missed color coded my post. I updated it.

Comment: At this point, better show your whole php code, the problem sounds to be there

Comment: System = Ubuntu, `.` is just a test result of my script.

Comment: @Tensibai : Sure, will do. I'm on it.

Comment: I uploaded it. I really that hope you can spot something.

Comment: Aww, gosh, the `.com` missing...

Comment: I really appreciated your willingness to help on this. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the different between white and green color code ?

green is for files executable (+x), due to your previous chmod 777

> Why does it place under the dot . ?

I assume you did a `ls -altr` wich sort the entries by modification time in ascending order, each time a file is created, the directory inode is modified, so it's listed just before your file (directory modified at file creation, file modified when all text has been written)

> Does it mean anything at all ?

Well, generally speaking yes, for your error in particular, we have no clue from wich directory you're starting from, if it writes relative to where you are, it's normal you don't find the files.

Try `ls /home/forge/biossantibodies.com/files/product-exports/`and if you get an error, `cd /home/forge/biossantibodies.com/` and rerun your php command.

Comment: I tried `ls /home/forge/biossantibodies.com/files/product-exports/` I see a lot of files listed fine.
I tried `php /home/forge/biossantibodies.com/artisan products:exportdiff --env=production` again as suggested, I got the same error again `Could not open local file: /home/forge/biossantibodies/files/product-exports/export1084_2016-11-23.csv.` … OMG  this is so annoying.

Comment: @ihue can you try `cd /home/forge/biossantibodies.com/ && pwd && php /home/forge/biossantibodies.com/artisan products:exportdiff --env=production` and post the console output in your question just to ensure what's happening ?

Comment: I tried your command, and add the console output in my post as requested.

Comment: I found the issue guys, you're right. It's in the code.

Answer (score 1):

- Executable files: **Green**
- Directory: **Blue**
- Image files(jpg, gif, bmp, png, tif): **Magenta**
- Symbolic links: **Cyan**
- Pipe: **Yellow**
- Socket: **Magenta**
- Orphaned symbolic links: **Blinking Bold white with red
  background**
- Block device driver: **Bold yellow foreground, with black
  background**
- Missing links along with files they point to: **Blinking Bold white
  with red background**
- Archives or compressed files(like tar,gz,zip,rpm): **Red**
- The directory has a link to itself in the **.** entry
- Each of its sub-directories has a link back via **..**
  So it doesn't seem anything special with the file permission please check the way you are accessing the file or share code.

Comment: I updated my post with my entire PHP. Can you please take a look ?

Comment: I found the issue guys, you're right. It's in the code.